# Neural Networks- What influences the choice of Optimizer more? - Specific Model Architecture or the Input Data Distribution(type, preprocessing etc)?

Tags: neural-networks, stochastic-gradient-descent, transfer-learning

Basically I am implementing a CNN on custom data. I cannot go into specifics but I notice that no matter what type of model I use (For example: A custom model, or even Transfer Learning models such as InceptionV3) SGD seems to performing better. From what I knew RMSProp was the preferred choice for Inception but it is performing particularly poorly.

So what exactly influences the choice of Optimizer. I know SGD is performing better, but why?